# How to open a web page inside of my own .net offline application?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, desktop

I need to develop own .NET off-line application which will just open a web page inside it. Basically I just need to open a web browser (like Internet Explorer 9) in my own offline app window and my web application inside it.

How to do that please?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using? Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation?

Anyway for both of them exists `WebBrowser` control:

[Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx)
[Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to open a web page inside the user's standard web browser? If so,

```
Process.Start("http://example.com/yoururl")
```

Or do you want a web browser physically inside your application's window? If so, use the `WebBrowser` control.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Forms
[WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx)

WPF [WPF - WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\myPath\myFile.htm")

or

Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: Make sure to quote your "c:\\..." path properly. And I have my .htm files set up to open in Google Chrome, not Internet Explorer.